# How do I scroll down a chatbox (div) automatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've been working on a chat application and now I need to scroll automatically when a message appears.
I've tried different things but they do not work unfortunately.
So this is my main.js code:

```
var lastTimeID = 0;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#btnSend').click( function() {

    sendChatText();
    $('#chatInput').val("");
  });
  startChat();
});

function startChat(){
  setInterval( function() { getChatText(); }, 2000);

}

function getChatText() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/refresh.php?lastTimeID=" + lastTimeID
  }).done( function( data )
  {
    var jsonData = JSON.parse(data);
    var jsonLength = jsonData.results.length;
    var html = "";
    var message = $('#view_ajax');
    for (var i = 0; i < jsonLength; i++) {
      var result = jsonData.results[i];
      html += '<div>(' + result.chattime + ') <b>' + result.usrname +'</b>: ' + result.chattext + '</div>';
      lastTimeID = result.id;

    }
    $('#view_ajax').append(html);
    message.html(data);
      message.scrollTop(message[0].scrollHeight);

  });
}

function sendChatText(){
  var chatInput = $('#chatInput').val();
  if(chatInput != ""){
    $.ajax({
      type: "GET",
      url: "/submit.php?chattext=" + encodeURIComponent( chatInput )
    });
  }
}
```

I've used

```
var message = $('#view_ajax');
message.html(data);
message.scrollTop(message[0].scrollHeight);
```

I really have no clue how jQuery works. I've tried a couple of things before this but it didn't work also.

Do you have any suggestion? Any advice? 
Do you need any more information? Feel free to ask!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scroll div top on page load then set scroll to work normally](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32318922/scroll-div-top-on-page-load-then-set-scroll-to-work-normally)

Comment: Are you getting the entire chat every time `getChatText()` is run?

Comment: @rybo111 Yes I do, it's still in developement ^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give each message an ID, as follows:

```
<div id="msg-1234">
```

Then you can scroll to this element using this jQuery:

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#msg-1234').offset().top }, 'slow');
```

Alternatively, put a div at the bottom of your chat:

```
<div id="chat-end"></div>
```

And scroll to this ID instead.

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/wfjmhbo9/)

Comment: Alright I've tried this, I'm assuming you put `$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#msg-1234').offset().top }, 'slow');` in `function getChatText()` because it runs every 2 seconds?

Comment: @Sj03rs No, because otherwise if the user scrolls up to read an old message, the window will autoscroll. You only want to autoscroll at the start of a chat, or when a new message comes in.

Comment: Yeah thanks, figured that out.. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sj03rs No problem. In an ideal world it wouldn't autoscroll when a new message comes in as that may frustrate the user, unless their scroll position is at the bottom currently. If you can make the user aware a new message has arrived without adjusting their scroll position that would be ideal.

Comment: Yeah, I'm going to do that!